# Smoothness and smoothness over formal neighborhood

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, schemes, smoothness

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a locally finitely presented map. Let $x\in X$ and $y=f(x)$.

We assume that the map on the level of fomal neighborhoods $X_{x}\rightarrow Y_{y}$ is formally smooth, can we find a étale neighborhood $S$ of $x$, such that $S\rightarrow Y$ is smooth at $x$.

Comment: Please give precise definitions for $X_x$ and $Y_y$.

Comment: the completion of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, same for $Y$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field and $Y=\mathrm{Spec}\,R$ where $R=\bigcup_{n>0}k[[t^{1/n}]]$ is the ring of Puiseux series over $k$. Take $X=\mathrm{Spec}\,(R/tR)$, $f=$ the obvious embedding. The maximal ideal $m$ of $R$ satisfies $m=m^2$, and the same holds in $R/tR$, so both completions are equal to $k$, but of course $f$ is not smooth.

Comment: Dear Laurent. This comment is just to be sure that I understand things properly. Compared to Grothendieck's criterion in (EGA IV, 17.5.3), what is missing in the statement given by prochet is the assumption that $Y$ is locally noetherian, isn't it?

Comment: Right. Without this assumption, taking completions (of local rings) may lead to strange things.

Comment: And meanwhile, I have realized that the same example was given by Anton Geraschenko in answer to [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/195/is-there-an-example-of-a-formally-smooth-morphism-which-is-not-smooth).

Comment: and can we find an example if $Y=\mathbb{A}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: @prochet: as ACL notes, there is no such example if $Y$ is locally noetherian.

Comment: so then, for such a $Y$, we can find an etale neighborhood as mentioned in the question? More generally, if we have a scheme $X$ and a point x, such that $X_{x}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{\mathbb{N}}_{y}$ can we also find such an etale neighborhood?

Comment: Also I don't see why $\mathbb{A}^{\mathbb{N}}=Spec(k[x_{i}])_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is locally noetherian.

Comment: @prochet: sorry, I had misread $\mathbb{A}^n$ for  $\mathbb{A^N}$. And no, I don't know an example.